# invoking url with RESTTEmplate and binding response with JAXB

Tags: xml, rest, xml-parsing, jaxb, resttemplate

using this code i hava an url to invoke 
when i invoke this url using a navigator i hav an xml reponse that i want to retreive in an object named Response annotated by JAXB

```
@Test
public void testRestTemplate()
{
    List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
    acceptableMediaTypes.add(new MediaType("application", "xml"));
    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);
    HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
      String url= "http://1.......bf93af6" ; 

      ResponseEntity<ListResponse> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url ,HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, ListResponse.class);
      ListBigBlueButtonResponse listResponses = responseEntity.getBody(); 

}
```

so ihava this Failure Trace :

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.alpha.vconf.test.ListResponse] and content type [text/xml;charset=utf-8]
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:107)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:688)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:674)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:492)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:447)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:394)
at com.alpha.vconf.test.VisioConfMangerTest.testRestTemplate(VisioConfMangerTest.java:43)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

can i have  any xml response in an object that i map using JAXB 
R: in my respnse object i have the same attribute that i have in my response as XMLELEMENT annotated by @XmlElement and the class is annotated by @XmlRootElement

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this exception because you have not added a suitable Http message converter for `Content-Type` `application/xml` to rest template that can be used by it to serialize/deserialize objects. By default, there are a few message converters in rest template but sometimes there is a need to explicitly add one/more like below. Here something that works for me to deserialize an XML response into an object.

```
XStreamMarshaller marshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
Map<String, Class> aliases = new HashMap<String, Class>();
aliases.put("person", Person.class); //"person" is root element.This is case sensitive
marshaller.setAliases(aliases);
MarshallingHttpMessageConverter converter = new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter(
            marshaller, marshaller);
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    converters.add(converter);
template.setMessageConverters(converters);
HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(null, headers);
ResponseEntity<Person> response = template.exchange(url,
            HttpMethod.GET, request, Person.class);
```